# Null on VideoView

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-videoview

I am making a video player that will stream a video from a server. I have checked so the video url is right and works! It is really late and all so I have probably missed something but why is this

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse("www.xxx.xxx/video.mp4");
    videoView.setVideoURI(video);
    videoView.start();
```

giving me this error

```
08-11 02:14:25.217  12390-12390/com.shredacademy.guitarmethodsintroductiontotheory E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.shredacademy.guitarmethodsintroductiontotheory, PID: 12390
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.setVideoURI(android.net.Uri)' on a null object reference
            at com.shredacademy.guitarmethodsintroductiontotheory.videoC.onViewCreated(videoC.java:56)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2871)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17562)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: `videoView` is `null`, so the parent `view` does not contain a `VideoView` with an id of `R.id.videoView`. Check your layout.

Comment: Can you post additional Java context, and the Layout that `videoView` exists in? Click [edit] to add the contents to your original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`videoView` is null because your parent view (`view`) doesn't have a `VideoView` that matches the resource id in `R.id.videoView`, so calling `view.findViewById(R.id.videoView)` returns null.

I noticed in your exception log that you are using `ViewPager`. Remember that, in order to access the fragment views, you should inflate the layout on the fragment before your findViewById:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recyclerview, container, false);
}
```

If you are sure your `view` is the correct cointainer for the VideoView, find the layout to which your `view` object is pointing to and add:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Then `VideoView videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView)` should now correctly return the declared view and inflate your videoView.

If your VideoView should be located somewhere else, then you have to inflate the videoView from it's correct parent:

`VideoView videoView = (VideoView) viewThatContainsVideoView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that the view `videoView` exists in a layout file or it would be throwing a compile error. Where may I ask is the above code? And can you post additional context?

Know that `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_id)` needs to be called to set the layout before you can call `findViewById()`, otherwise that call will return nothing but `null`.